# Is there any way to collect script of running SP with it's input value using DMVs?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using below script to collect information about active sessions. It returns Query/SP (script), it's estimated E-Plan, resource consumption and other information.

I know to use profiler to collect script of SP with it's input value but because performance of SP varies on different input value, `it's not good idea to run profile for long time, so I want to collect it using DMV.

Is there any way to get it (exec sp_name input1, input2, input3, ..) using DMV?

```
select
            db_name(sp.dbid),sp.spid,er.wait_type,er.wait_time,er.wait_resource,er.total_elapsed_time,st.text,qp.query_plan
            ,ec.net_packet_size,ec.client_net_address,es.host_name,es.program_name,es.client_interface_name
            ,es.status,es.cpu_time,qmg.granted_memory_kb,es.total_scheduled_time,es.total_elapsed_time
            ,es.reads,es.writes,es.logical_reads

from
                sys.dm_exec_requests er
inner join      master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
on              er.session_id=sp.spid
inner join      sys.dm_exec_connections ec
on              er.session_id=ec.session_id
inner join      sys.dm_exec_sessions es
on              ec.session_id=es.session_id
inner join      sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants qmg
on er.session_id=qmg.session_id
cross apply     (select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle)) st
cross apply     (select * from sys.dm_exec_query_plan(er.plan_handle)) qp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a possible method here - [Getting the Query Plans and Parameters Directly from the Plan Cache](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#otherreasons)

Comment: Scott, it is not possible to get the parameter values of active sessions. The article you linked to here is good and has lots of useful info, but it also shows that you can only get the parameter values used for plan compilation. You can only get runtime parameter values that way if you run the query.

Comment: @srutzky - thanks, honestly, I only skimmed the information, but thought I'd pass it along

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to get input parameter values outside of a SQL Profiler trace or equivalent Extended Events session. Extended Events are less resource intensive so you should be able to run that for longer than the SQL Profiler trace.

The plan cache can't show anything besides values passed in the first time and were used to compile the execution plan. Not only are these values *not* runtime values  (well, unless that plan only ran once), they are most likely the opposite of what you are looking for since those values were used to produce the best possible plan in the allowed time, and it will be other values being passed in that don't work well with that plan that cause the issues that you are investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) by Adam Machanic. It's highly powerful, can give you all the information you need, and can run frequently, loading its results to a table.